# Excel VBA crashes after a larger number of rows

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I have created an Excel macro to run an analysis for a larger dataset (~24,000 lines). The macro is working well for the first c. 2,000 requests/lines but thereafter generally crashes. The request/line number, at which the crash occurs, thereby varies.

The debugger, which is appearing at that point, highlights that the code line leading to the crash is:

```
Cells(i, 7).Value = var1.innerText
```

I have already checked other threads and solutions on this topic, including a suggested change from 'Int' to 'Long' etc - none of these worked however. Can anyone help why the macro is working well for smaller requests but failing after a certain number of lines?

The code I am using is pasted below. Many thanks in advance.

```
Sub Gethits()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim var As String
Dim var1 As Object

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 1654 To lastRow

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 4) & "&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A" & Cells(i, 5) & "%2Ccd_max%3A" & Cells(i, 6) & "&tbm=nws"

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rso")
Set var1 = html.getElementById("resultStats")
Cells(i, 7).Value = var1.innerText

DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)

End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote a class for [Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations
](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196922/171419) that handles 50+ requests at a time.  It will drastically speed up your code.

Comment: For now I loading the information into an array and writing all the rows at once is your best bet.   It is also possible that the server is limiting the number of requests in a given time period.

Comment: What's the error, specifically? Your code is assuming `var1` isn't `Nothing`, could it be error 91?

Comment: And have your XMLHTTP object created outside the loop. You can add code to introduce waits at specified step intervals in your loop to help mitigate hitting with lots of requests too quickly.

Comment: `Option Explicit` every time. *Every time* - at the top of every module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. The restriction indeed seems to be driven by Google limiting the number of requests in a given time period. When visiting the Google webpage after the error occurs, I am asked to run trough a captcha process due to unsually high request activity.

The idea of submitting multiple requests at a time seems very interesting in any case, as it would save a lot of time collecting the data. Is there, however, a simplified approach to the example by TinMan (codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196922/171419)? I have checked for other threads but have not found anything helpful thus far.